# How to assign non-printable ascii character to a char variable

Tags: c#

How can I assign a non-printable ascii character to a char variable?

The table is here : http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have at least [few possibilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/x9h8tsay.aspx) to assign a value to char:

```
var chr = 'X';        // Character literal
var chr = '\x0058';   // Hexadecimal
var chr = (char)88;   // Cast from integral type
var chr = '\u0058';   // Unicode
```

You can also use:

```
var chr = Convert.ToChar(32);
```

or, mainly for reference, the most complex and probably unnecessary:

```
var chr = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[] { 32 }).First();
```